# $\text{Top}(\mathbb{R}^2,\mathbb{R}^2)$ isn't contractible?

Tags: algebraic-topology

I've seen a claim that the space of maps from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to itself isn't contractible. Anyone have a proof or source?

Comment: Isn't $G(t,f)=tf$ a deformation onto the zero function?

Comment: That seems right. I'll contact the person who said it, maybe I misunderstood something.

Comment: Maybe they meant the group of self-homeomorphisms of $\mathbb{R}^n$, sometimes denoted $\mathrm{Top}(n)$?  I think that for $n = 2$, $\mathrm{Top}(2)$ deformation retracts onto $O(2)$, so is non-contractible.